# convert List<object> in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of object:

```
  List<CartItemModel> cartItems;
```

my `CartItemModel` class is:

```
  class CartItemModel {
  String name, price, currency;
  int quantity;

  CartItemModel({
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.currency = "GBP",
  });
}
```

Now i want to convert it to:

```
List items = [
  {
    "name": itemName,
    "quantity": quantity,
    "price": itemPrice,
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "name": itemName,
    "quantity": quantity,
    "price": itemPrice,
    "currency": "GBP"
  }
];
```

Just simply assigning `List items = cartItems;` isn;t working.

Comment: You have to either manually assign them, or create a special constructor that takes the specific JSON properties and assigns them to your Class variables.

Comment: isn't there any solution so that i can just create a loop inside items and create that key value pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding toJSON to your model ..
this is complete example

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Convert',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Convert Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<CartItemModel> cartItems = [CartItemModel(name: "name1", price: "price1", quantity: 1), CartItemModel(name: "name2", price: "price2", quantity: 2), CartItemModel(name: "name3", price: "price3", quantity: 3)];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  List items = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(cartItems));
                  print(items);
                },
                child: Text("convert")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CartItemModel {
  String name, price, currency;
  int quantity;

  CartItemModel({
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.currency = "GBP",
  });

  Map toJson() => {"name": name, "quantity": quantity, "price": price, "currency": "GBP"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new constructor, specifically for Maps like JSON:

```
class CartItemModel {
  String name, price, currency;
  int quantity;

  CartItemModel({
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.currency = "GBP",
  });

  /// New constructor
  CartItemModel.fromMap(Map map) :
      this.name = map['name'],
      this.price = map['price'],
      this.quantity = map['quantity'],
      this.currency = map['currency'];
}
```

```
items.forEach((item) {
  itemModelList.add(CartItemModel.fromMap(item));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a `.toJson()` method in your model.

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> _CartItemModelToJson(CartItemModel instance) => <String, dynamic>{
    'name': instance.itemName,
    'quantity': instance.quantity,
    'price': instance.itemPrice,
    'currency': instance.currency,
};
```

and convert your `List<CartItemModel>` to a `Map` with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write toJSON and fromJSON manually in your class. Or you can use

> dependencies:   # Your other regular dependencies here
> json_annotation: <latest_version>
>
> dev_dependencies:   # Your other dev_dependencies here   build_runner:
> <latest_version>   json_serializable: <latest_version>

You can look for details : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 0):

You should use a fromJson where you can pass the map as a JSON and it will give you back a list of your objects.

```
class CartItemModel {
  String name, price, currency;
  int quantity;

  CartItemModel({
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.currency = "GBP",
  });

  CartItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        price = json['price'],
        currency = json['currency'],
        quantity = json['quantity'];
}

void main() {
  List<CartItemModel> items = [
    CartItemModel(
      currency: "GBP",
      quantity: 100,
      price: "200",
      name: "First name",
    ),
  ];

  print(items);

  List<CartItemModel> itemsFromJson = [
    {"name": "Second name", "quantity": 3, "price": "50", "currency": "GBP"},
    {"name": "third name", "quantity": 2, "price": "60", "currency": "GBP"}
  ].map((e) => CartItemModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  
  print(itemsFromJson);
  print(itemsFromJson[0].name);
}
```